# Test to compare difference in location estimates between sex

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, spatial

[image]I have geolocation data for the locations of ~20 animals. I want to know if there is a sex-specific difference (female orange), but geolocation data is very broad scale i.e.

M Long: -11, Lat: 8
F Long: -10.5, Lat 6

This is for R gui. I have tried very simple tests (wilcoxs) which suggests there is a difference, but these only account for either longitude or latitude, not both. Any advice on which package/function would be most appropriate to use to further determine if there is a difference? 
Pinpoint analysis (Spatstat) was suggested but I'm unsure my data qualifies for its use due to broad resolution of geodata. Likewise was ade4 to find a home range estimate then compare the centroids, however I have a small sample size (only 5 females) so this appears to not be possible, in addition I am not interested in range, merely difference in distribution.

Comment: Start with plotting this on a map, and show us!

Comment: - Those lines are error bars? What is the basis for them? Why are they only in vertical direction and not horizontal? - How would you model the spread of the locations of the animals, how do you sample the animals, what do you want to test? (e.g. the data shows an obvious difference between the orange and black points but whether this also means a sex-specific difference remains the question, e.g. it is not known whether your sampling method is prejudiced).

Comment: Thanks for the interest. This is geolocator data associated with a migratory species, with male and females tagged in breeding grounds, then tracked to the wintering grounds (which is shown), therefore no prejudice is present.
The error bars are confusing! - With geolocator data you typically only display errors correlated with the sun elevation angle, in this example there are latitudinal error, but no longitudinal. 
I am interested in a difference between the points, these are the averaged wintering location produced over a period of 5 months, for males and females